# Domain joined VM+ snapshotting

Tags: windows-8, active-directory, hyper-v

I have been using a Win 8 Hyper V VM with snapshots to test some applications I am writing in fresh environments (to ensure that it works in a non dev environment,etc)

The way I use it is that I create a snapshot after a fresh install, install my application, test and then revert to the snapshot I had created.

This works fine, except that after a few weeks, I get an error message related to "trust relationship between workstation and primary domain failed"

Is there a way to prevent this issue? (other than updating the clean snapshot every few days)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your only options are to change the default machine password age for computers in AD, or create an exception for that VM, which isn't really recommended security-wise.

Or you can dis-join and re-join the domain every time you revert your snapshot.

[MSDN](https://web.archive.org/web/20151209151102/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/mikekol/archive/2009/03/18/does-restoring-a-snapshot-break-domain-connectivity-here-s-why.aspx)

[VMware](https://web.archive.org/web/20170913063350/https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US)

[Microsoft](https://web.archive.org/web/20131128084205/http://support.microsoft.com:80/kb/295049)

Comment: dis joining and rejoining when the trust fails should be good enough right? (I revert 2-3 times a day)

Comment: If you dis-join and re-join it will be fine for that session. If you revert back to the old snapshot, you're going to be off again, unless you create a new snapshot after you dis-join and re-join.